# Is it possible to set multiple languages for spell check in a mixed-language notebook?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, spellchecker

I am working in a notebook that uses a mix of two languages, is it possible to allow for both dictionaries to by used simultaneously? I have tried:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], DefaultNaturalLanguage] = {"English", "Swedish"}
```

to no avail.

Comment: Did you found a find a solution?

Comment: no solution as of yet

Comment: any solutions found?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible by using the [DefaultNaturalLanguage](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultNaturalLanguage.html) option. We can set the language for the whole notebook to with:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], "DefaultNaturalLanguage"] = "English"
```

And then we can set the language of some of the cells to a different language by adding a different "DefaultNaturalLanguage" option to cells that we want spelled with a different dictionary. This can be done in several ways:

1. Option inspector. Right click the cell bracket and select "Properties" and type Natural in the search box to find the DefaultNaturalLanguage option for the cell and change it.
2. Show Expression. Select the cell and then select "Cell->Show Expression" from the menu bar. There you can add the option manually.
3. Evaluate this code in a cell immediately after the text cell that you want to change its language:

   ```
    SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], Previous, Cell];
    With[{cell = SelectedCells[][[1]]}, 
        SetOptions[cell, "DefaultNaturalLanguage" -> "Swedish"]];
   ```
4. If you are going to be doing this frequently, I would make a palette to make this easier.

Notice that this doesn't solve the case of mixed languages in a single cell, which is a common case for me. Maybe this can be done with cells inside cells, but then setting the options becomes quite complicated so a palette would need to be developed to make this practical.